# Controlling Light components C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game mechanic where the player can toggle the car headlights with the `L` keypress and the backlights witht he `S` key, which also controls backwards movement.
This is shown in the code below.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class headLights : MonoBehaviour {

    private Light frontLight;
    private Light backLight;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    frontLight = GetComponent<Light>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
    {
        frontLight.enabled = !frontLight.enabled;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        backLight = GetComponent<Light>();
        backLight.enabled = !backLight.enabled;
    }
}
```

}

The problem is when I press `L` or `S`, both the front and back lights turn on because which I assume, the GetComponent refers to all extra Light components in the Scene and generalizes them as one. 
I want to get the `S` key to only turn on the "backLights" while it is pressed and the `L` key to only toggle the "frontLights".

**METHODS I HAVE USED TO TRY FIX THE PROBLEM**

```
    frontLight = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Light>();
```

This code just gives me errors like "the gameobject player does not have any light components attached to it(although it clearly does) blah blah blah.

I have also tried using tags but they confuse me a lot and seem like the easy way out. I know in the future I will have to learn how to do object orientated syntax and coding so I would very much like to learn how to reference it!

Please help me if you can, it would make my day~~ :)

Please note, you do not have to solve the whole problem for me if you are short on time, just giving general syntax that I can just swap out would help me a great deal!

Comment: `This code just gives me errors like "the gameobject player does not have any light components attached to it(although it clearly does) blah blah blah.` Compilers are seldom mistaken ;-)

Comment: There's a few ideas [here on the Unity forums](https://answers.unity.com/questions/162678/how-to-distinguish-between-multiple-components-of.html). It looks like you need to `GetComponents<Light>()` plural and iterate through the list to work out which one is which from other properties. But I've never worked with Unity so I'll leave it for someone else to write a correct answer!

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Sorry ;/ I joined yesterday so not that great even at asking questions yet haha

Comment: FYI: GetComponent<Light>() only checks on the current GameObject (so where your script is added as component).

You can get a list of children components by GetComponentsInChildren<Light>() and distinguish by the GameObject's names if needed.

The answer of Leo Bartkus works for sure, so please accept it then :)

Answer (score 3):

Its really easy to disambiguate the two lights.  Just make the variables public and set them in the inspector.  Be sure to null check them before you use them to make sure they are set.

I just realized that probably didn't make sense.

Lets say your hierarchy is set up like this with the light objects as children to the car:

```
car
+-FrontLight
+-RearLight
```

Instead of putting the custom behavior on the light gameobjects, you should put it on the car.

Then, the behavior would look like this:

```
 public class headLights : MonoBehaviour {

    public Light frontLight;
    public Light backLight;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
    {
        if(frontLight != null) {
            frontLight.enabled = !frontLight.enabled;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        if(backLight != null) {
            backLight.enabled = !backLight.enabled;
        }
    }
}
```

This is because the lights are not Components of the car, they are Children of it.

Comment: Hello Leo, I just made them public which allowed me to put the differentiate the lights however the problem persists. I have no idea what null checking is(sorry)

Comment: Null checking means that `GetComponent()` is allowed to return `null` if it didn't find anything: "Returns the component with name type if the game object has one attached, null if it doesn't." If you assume that it does return an object and you got null instead then your code will crash when you try to use the reference. That said if you're sure that your code will only ever be used on the right object, and if there's no way for you to recover if it isn't, then you could ignore this and let it crash at least during development.